# C++ Printing array of struct objects

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a problem with printing an array of struct objects.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define LOG(x) std::cout << x
#define ARR_SIZE(arr) sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])

struct vec2
{
    int x, y;
};

struct Painting : vec2
{
    std::string s_author, s_title, s_genre;
};

void disp_Array(Painting arr[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE(arr); i++)
    {
        LOG(arr[i].s_author << "\n");
        LOG(arr[i].s_title << "\n");
        LOG(arr[i].s_genre << "\n");
        LOG(arr[i].x << "\n");
        LOG(arr[i].y << "\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    Painting painting[4];

    disp_Array(painting);

    for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < ARR_SIZE(painting), j <= ARR_SIZE(painting); i++, j++)
    {
        LOG("Painting " << j << "\n");
        LOG("Author: ");
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::getline(std::cin, painting[i].s_author);

        LOG("Title: ");
        std::getline(std::cin, painting[i].s_title);

        LOG("Genre: ");
        std::getline(std::cin, painting[i].s_genre);

        LOG("Width: ");
        std::cin >> painting[i].x;

        LOG("Height: ");
        std::cin >> painting[i].y;

        LOG("\n");
    }

    disp_Array(painting);

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is within the disp_Array function. The idea was that the function should output the variables from objects which are in an array. But unfortunately it doesn't work, in fact, it doesn't output anything.

Therefore I tried to test it by replacing the function's body with just displaying the size of the array, but it prints 0 instead of 4 (the number of elements in that array).

Does that mean that the problem is within the function's parameters and how I pass them? Because on its own, ARRAY_SIZE works very well.

Comment: You can't copy C-style arrays, and thus can't pass them as parameters. Use `std::array` or `std::vector`, which both have a `size()` member function.

Comment: Your `ARR_SIZE` only work with *real* arrays. Once you pass the array to a function, it will decay to a *pointer* to its first element (as an argument `Painting arr[]` is equal to `Painting* arr`). And using `sizeof` on a pointer gives the size of the pointer and not what it points to. My advice is to stop using old simple plain C-style arrays, and instead use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: Thank you. I had that feeling that I should do it how it should be done and ease my life, but still I gave it a try.

Also there is something strange, when I enter the second element's variables it skips Author. I fixed that with cin.ignore() but I should then press enter, how can I avoid pressing enter and still have that problem fixed?

Comment: @JohnDavis: it would be a different question but lies in the mixing of `getline` (line oriented) and `cin>>` (field oriented). After reading a field followed by enter, the end of line is still in input buffer and causes the next `getline` to return an (almost) empty line. Long story short, dont mix.